# Is it safe to do recursive compression with tar, gzip and pigz?

Tags: backup, tar, recursive, compression, gzip

If I make a `.tar.gz` via

`tar czvf - ./myfiles/ | pigz -9 -p 16 > ./mybackup.tar.gz`,

Can I safely unzip an *already gzip'd* file `./myfiles/an_old_backup.tar.gz` *within* the `./myfiles` directory via

```
gzip -d mybackup.tar.gz
tar -xvf mybackup.tar
cd myfiles
gzip -d an_old_backup.tar.gz
tar -xvf an_old_backup.tar
```

? And can one do this recursive compression safely *ad infinitum*?

Comment: Your question seems corrupted, did you proof read it? Are you asking is it safe to zip/tar  a zip/tar file? (I.e. will there be data lose if I do this?)

Comment: Notes: (1) `tar f -` is weird, you could just omit the `f` switch, (2) the calls to `gzip` seem extraneous; `tar xz` will take care of unzipping by itself.

Comment: The calls to `gzip` are required when using `pigz` in the initial compression. Otherwise the `tar` extraction fails.

Comment: I meant the calls to gzip when extracting; `gzip -d mybackup.tar.gz` will delete `mybackup.tar.gz`, causing the following `tar ... mybackup.tar.gz` to fail.

Comment: oh, right -- I edited to `tar ... mybackup.tar`. ty

Comment: But then you should also get rid of the `z`, since the input to tar is not gzip-compressed anymore :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question can be rephrased as "is it OK to have compressed
archives within compressed archives?", then the answer is "yes".

This may not be the most convenient (as you note, you will have to run
tar several files to get everything unpacked), and applying
compression to data that has already been compressed may not yield an
additional reduction in size, but it will all work.

Comment: That's a good rephrase but I want to make sure this is true even using `tar`, `gzip` and `pigz` in tandem.

Comment: The answer is still "yes". `pigz` is meant to produce the same output as `gzip`, just using computing resources differently.

Comment: I tried one recursion and it worked... Probably should have just tried first, thanks for answer

Answer (score 5):

```
tar czvf - ./myfiles/ | pigz -9 -p 16 > ./mybackup.tar.gz
```

is the equivalent of

```
tar cvf - ./myfiles/ | gzip | pigz -9 -p 16 > ./mybackup.tar.gz
```

You're not obtaining a `tar.gz` but a `tar.gz.gz`, an archive compressed twice, not a compressed archive of compressed files.

That is pointless. Compressed output is not compressible. You won't get any significant space gain by compressing twice. And for extracting, you'd need to decompress twice as well with

```
gunzip < mybackup.tar.gz | gunzip | tar xf -
```

Or

```
gunzip < mybackup.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

If you want to use `pigz` instead of plain `gzip` for the compression, just do:

```
tar cvf - ./myfiles/ | pigz -9 -p 16 > ./mybackup.tar.gz
```

Which you can uncompress with `tar zxvf mybackup.tar.gz`

Also note that you should never have to uncompress a `tar.gz` file and store the uncompressed version on disk. The whole point of compressors like `gzip`/`pigz`, `bzip2`/`pbzip2`, `xz`/`pixz` is that they can work on streams, you just insert them in a pipeline.

Comment: I see. I was being excessive with the double-zippin'. ty